# AngularJS - Deletion from list lags when using ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I am using the `ngAnimate` module in my project to animate items in my list on a certain condition. The problem is if I use `ngAnimate` then deletion from list takes a little bit more time than without animation. [Please check the plunker I've created.](http://plnkr.co/edit/6wDlTh5xbNzk2H0oeLJe?p=preview)

This is my HTML:

```
<body ng-app="JU">
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h3>Non Laggin List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items" class="">{{i}}<button ng-click="remove($index)">Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <h3>Lagging List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items2" class="animated error">{{i}}<button ng-click="remove2($index)">Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var JU = angular.module('JU', [
  'ngAnimate'
]);

JU.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 $scope.items = [
   'Hello',
   'Click',
   'To Delete',
   'ME from',
   'This list'
 ];
 $scope.items2 = [
   'Hello',
   'Click',
   'To Delete',
   'ME from',
   'This list'
 ];
 $scope.remove = function (index) {
     $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
 };
 $scope.remove2 = function (index) {
     $scope.items2.splice(index, 1);
 };
}]);
```

Deleting from the first list is fast and responsive. Deletion from the second list feels laggy and unresponsive. I am using an implementation similar to the second list in my code. Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: @PSL Is that a question or an answer?

Comment: Just add a question mark? how can that be an answer? :) So you do not need any animation when deleted? Does it make sense with a question mark now..?

Comment: @PSL Yeah. Sorry. No I dont need any animation when an element is added or removed from the list. I'm doing animation on class change. However, the point is, with the animation class, the list item takes time to delete. Without it, it deletes fine. How is that?

Comment: That is because of the animation that you have provided in the `animated` class. You need to reset them for ng-repeat animation classes..Check this:- http://plnkr.co/edit/9l78bS?p=preview When you have ngAnimate included in your module, it will add nganimate classes to the element and tries to apply the animation duration specified.

Comment: @PSL PLease add that as an answer and I'll accept it. I did not know something like this happens too. Thanks!

Comment: Added as answer. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have `ngAnimate` included in your module, ng-repeat addition, deletion etc will add classes on the affected element for adding transitions for the animated class. This will apply when you have transition mentioned in the original class, ngAnimate will wait for that much duration (assuming animation to happen on the affected element) before it removes the element from DOM. But you have not specified any animation for the ng-repeat animation classes. So you see that behavior of a delay happening when element is removed. Since you do not need any animation for removal of items from the repeat, just turnoff animation by overriding rules for animation classes.

Try adding these:-

```
.animated.ng-move,
.animated.ng-enter,
.animated.ng-leave {
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
  animation-duration: 0s;
}
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9l78bS?p=preview)**